# How is 'this' resolved in Array.prototype.forEach when an arrow function in provided?

Tags: javascript, foreach, arrow-functions, lexical-scope

Here is my code:

```js
class Employee {
  constructor(ename) {
    this.ename = ename;
  }
}

class EmployeeRenderer {
  constructor(employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
    this.ename = "EmployeeRenderer";
  }
  renderWithArrowFunc() {
    this.employees.forEach(emp => {
      console.log(this.ename); // Will print EmployeeRenderer 3 times
    })
  }
}


var employees = [
  new Employee('Alex'),
  new Employee('Bob'),
  new Employee('Smith')
];

var employeeRenderer = new EmployeeRenderer(employees);
employeeRenderer.renderWithArrowFunc();
```

As we know, in an arrow function, `this` is not a declared variable, so to resolve a reference to `this`, JavaScript consults with the enclosing scope(s). As such, in the above code, when `console.log(this.ename)` is being executed, JavaScript asks the first immediate enclosing lexical scope- the function `forEach`- about `this`. In `forEach` implementation** , `this` points at the value of the array on which the function has been called: `employees` and as it doesn't have `ename` property, so I expected to see `undefined` 3 times in the output than `EmployeeRenderer`. It shows that `this` has been resolved to `EmployeeRenderer.ename`. What am I missing here?

** I searched for an implementation of `forEach` and couldn't find one, hence I assume it must be identical to the [pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) mentioned in MDN.

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet and it logs out `undefined`, `undefined`, `undefined`

Comment: @NicholasTower Oops, I made too many mistakes. Fixed and updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: "*the first immediate enclosing lexical scope - the function `forEach`*" - no, a function call does not introduce a **lexical scope**. And certainly not one to the *implementation* of the called function.

Comment: @Bergi But `forEach` has a declaration anyway so it a nested scope is created for it. Am I wrong?

Comment: But in your code, `forEach` is not declared, and the arrow function is not defined within the implementation of `forEach`. It's just passed as an argument to a call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable scope is *lexical*. The code of `forEach` is not relevant to determining the scope of variables in the callback function. It's just the code that textually contains the arrow function definition, and the blocks around that, and so on.

So `this` refers to the context that was used to call `returnWithArrowFunct()`, which is the value of the `employeeRenderer` variable.

Comment: To be more precise, it's just the code that textually contains the *definition of the arrow function* (which is usually as the argument to the `forEach` call, but not necessarily).

Comment: True, I was referring to this specific example code, where they're the same thing. But I've edited it.

Comment: I still don't get it. How is `this` resolved? Isn't it resolved *lexically*?

Comment: When you call a function in the form `x.y()`, the value of `x` becomes the `this` context inside the function `y`. Then when calling the arrow function, it's resolved lexically, so it retains the binding from `y`.

Comment: @Hans Yes. [Lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_scope#Lexical_scoping) means that it doesn't look into the `forEach` implementation from which it was *called*.

Comment: @Bergi Exactly! So `this.employees` becomes the value of `this` inside the function `forEach`, right? And when the arrow function asks for `this`, what should be returned?

Comment: The arrow function isn't defined inside the definition of `forEach`, so it doesn't get its scope from it. Basically, if you can't see the source code of a function, it's not in the scope chain.

Comment: `this` inside the arrow function is the same as `this` outside the call to `forEach`.

Comment: It's just like any other local variable inside `renderWithArrowFunc`. That's one of the things that makes arrow functions different from traditional functions.

Comment: @Hans Yes, `employees` becomes the `this` context in the `employees.forEach()` call (i.e. in the body of the `forEach` method), but that's not the `this` value we are talking about - it's irrelevant for the arrow function because the arrow function is not defined in the body of the `forEach` method.

Comment: @Hans I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @Bergi Now I get it! Function call chain has nothing to do with lexical scopes. The latter is just about function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`this` has no property `ename` and points to the outer `this`. For getting a value, you need to take `emp.ename`

```js
class Employee {
  constructor(ename) {
    this.ename = ename;
  }
}

class EmployeeRenderer {
  constructor(employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
  }
  renderWithArrowFunc() {
    this.employees.forEach(emp => {
      console.log(emp.ename); // Will print Alex, Bob, Smith
    })
  }
}


var employees = [
  new Employee('Alex'),
  new Employee('Bob'),
  new Employee('Smith')
];

var employeeRenderer = new EmployeeRenderer(employees);
employeeRenderer.renderWithArrowFunc();
```